# How to split values in realtime database at cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

First of all, I am a newbie at Cloud functions. I am making a reminder. And I should get to time values. (named: start at) I can get them. But I have to split them all one by one. I will use them all to put down my Date object. But I do not know how can I do it. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
exports.scheduleremindernotifications = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/name').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const usersRef = admin.database().ref('users');
  usersRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const userId = childSnapshot.key;
      const consumingRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/missions`);
      consumingRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          const missions_keys = childSnapshot.key;

          // Start at time elde ettik.
          const startatref = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/missions/${missions_keys}/startat`);

          startatref.once('value').then(allToken => {
            if (allToken.val()) {
              const token = allToken.val();

              console.log(`${token}`);

              // Outputs:  6 5 2023 6 8 13 UTC+3 , 6 5 2023 6 8 13 UTC+3

              // I should split it all according to (" ") space such as:
              //  first[0]
              // second[1]
              // third[2]

              const date23 = new Date(first[0] + '/' + second[1] + '/' + third[2]).setHours(17, 30, 0);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is my firebase database structure:

[image]

Comment: split the output by " " and then `const date23 = new Date(+a[2],+(a[1]-1),+a[0]);
date23.setHours(17,30,0);` where `b` is the splitted array

Comment: I do not know  how to put down my values it. Also, I do not know use it. I just want to split it according to space (" "). I have searched for it but I could not find it.

Comment: const a = token.split(" ") ?